# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : while trying to create url path

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc

I get this client side error message while on an MVC controller i create an url.

```
ViewBag.uri = $"wss://{u.Ip}:{u.Port}";
```

and then i try to use it at client side as...

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  var uri = @ViewBag.uri;                   <-- The error is raised here
</script>
```

How can i escape the path and have the full url without any errors?

Comment: `var uri = '@ViewBag.uri';` - just add single/double quotes to treat it as URL string.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Great! Should you post it as an answer?

Comment: @OrElse Better to self-close as "Typo or not reproducible" as this question probably has limited value to other readers in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing quotes here .

```
var uri = @ViewBag.uri;
```

use this instead

```
var uri = '@ViewBag.uri';
```